# Java parse and calculate text file

Tags: java

I have a project that I've approached from many ways, however I can't seem to get it right. It's part of an android app that just records time clock punches and saves to a txt file in external storage. The txt file is formatted like this :

PUNCHIN Wed 05-15 03:50 PM

PUNCHOUT Wed 05-15 03:50 PM

PUNCHIN Wed 05-15 03:50 PM

PUNCHOUT Wed 05-15 03:50 PM

PUNCHIN Wed 05-15 03:50 PM

PUNCHOUT Wed 05-15 03:50 PM

PUNCHIN Wed 05-15 03:50 PM

PUNCHOUT Wed 05-15 03:50 PM

It will record punches in and out Sunday thru Saturday.

When the app reads in the file it creates an arraylist that is each one of those lines.

I have another array list that corresponds to each array element defined as a float that represents the hours  of the day of that punch. E.g: element one would be 15.83 and so on.

Then it would call a method to subtract the even elements from the odd elements and give a total of how many hours worked that day.

At this point I realize my approach is a bit off. I just want to take that array list that's been built from the text file and just calculate how many hours have been worked each day.

What is everyone's idea of the best approach for this?

Where I am at in this method, i have many arraylists and strings of  substrings, endless for loops and lots of spaghetti code.

Anyone's prospective would be appreciated. Thanks, Josh!

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: To solve problems like this, I often shut off my computer and get a pencil and paper to write out the steps needed. I use English words and don't worry overly about any Java syntax. It often helps to solve some examples by hand so I can think about the individual steps.

Comment: Good advice.. right now I've reduced it to 3 arraylists created in for loops. The last loop declares arraylist[num] = integer.parseint (array [num].substring (17,19)).. which goes through another loop subtracting: array1 - array0.

Comment: My background is PERL, PHP, SQL, HTML, CSS. I'm somewhat new to Java having only 2 months of daily usage. I could do this in perl in a heartbeat, but as I'm not  familiar with all the java api's out there I'm still experimenting with what I know

Comment: "right now I've reduced it to 3 arraylists created in for loops" IMO, this is still too focused on Java constructs. I suggest you back away from the "3 arraylists" and "for loops" and just describe the steps in plain English. Note that when you do this, you will naturally use words like "if" and "for each" which will translate very naturally into Java, but you should concentrate on using plain English as much as possible without worrying about Java syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I came to to resolve this task:

```
public void calculate (View v) {

    try {
        String view_data = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.history_view)).getText().toString();

        String[] data_array;
        data_array = view_data.split("\n");

        ArrayList<String> time_punches = new ArrayList<String>();
        // create arrayList of full data line
        for (int a = 0; a <= data_array.length - 1; a++) {
            if (!data_array[a].equals("")) {
                if (!data_array[a].equals("UPS")) {
                    if (!data_array[a].equals("Turkey Hill")) {
                        time_punches.add(data_array[a]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // create another arrayList of just the times, in string format
        ArrayList<String> nextList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int er = 0; er <= time_punches.size() - 1; er++) {

            if (time_punches.get(er).substring(0, 7).equals("PUNCHIN")) {
                nextList.add(time_punches.get(er).substring(18, 23));
            }

            if (time_punches.get(er).substring(0, 8).equals("PUNCHOUT")) {
                nextList.add(time_punches.get(er).substring(19, 24));
            }
        }

        // create another arrayList, converting string time format to floats
        int num_a;
        float num_b;
        float num_c;
        float num_d;
        ArrayList<Float> anotherList = new ArrayList<Float>();
        float[] floatArray = new float[nextList.size()];

        for (int _x = 0; _x <= nextList.size() - 1; _x++) {
            num_a = Integer.parseInt(nextList.get(_x).substring(0, 2));
            num_b = Integer.parseInt(nextList.get(_x).substring(3, 5));
            num_a = (num_a) + 12;
            num_b = (num_b) / 60;
            num_c = (num_a) + (num_b);
            anotherList.add(num_c);
            num_a = 0;
            num_b = 0;
            num_c = 0;
            num_d = 0;
        }

        // create yet again, another arrayList to calcuate the time punches grouped by two
        ArrayList<Float> calcList = new ArrayList<Float>();
        float num_e;
        int num_f;
        for (int _z = 0; _z <= anotherList.size() - 1; _z++) {
            num_f = (_z) + 1;
            if ((_z % 2) == 0) {
                calcList.add(anotherList.get(num_f) - anotherList.get(_z));
            }
        }

        // AT THIS POINT calcList contains the hours worked per day.

        // Now do something useful with this data (Hours worked per day)
        float all_hours = 0;
        for (int _y = 0; _y <= calcList.size() - 1; _y++) {
            all_hours += calcList.get(_y);
        }

        ArrayList<String> pretty_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int _a = 0; _a <= time_punches.size() - 1; _a++) {
            if ((_a % 2) == 0) {
                pretty_list.add(time_punches.get(_a).substring(8, 18));
            }
        }

        ArrayList<String> pretty2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int _s = 0; _s <= pretty_list.size() - 1; _s++) {
            pretty2.add(pretty_list.get(_s) + ": " + Float.toString(calcList.get(_s)) + "hours");
        }
        pretty2.add("\nTotal Hours Worked: " + Float.toString(all_hours) + "hours");

        String final_output_string = "";

        for (int _e = 0; _e <= pretty2.size() - 1; _e++) {
            final_output_string = final_output_string + pretty2.get(_e) + "\n";
        }

        // final_output_string is the end result, time_punches contains the raw data, calclist contains the floats of the raw data,
        // allhours is the float sum of all hours worked. Next, just set text to my textview and hope the user doent click the button twice! :)
        // oh, yeah. and all of this is assuming that all hours worked are in the PM. heh... version 2 will be better, hehe

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.history_view)).setText(final_output_string);

        alert("Punch Log Converted To Calculated Hours");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        alert("You May Still Be Punched In! Reload Time Punches!");
    }

}
```